# How to debug Nautilus extension?

Tags: nautilus, debug, extension

I recently installed `mpd-gnome` which among other things adds a nautilus extension `nautilus-mpd.py`. This extension does not seem to be working so I decided to run nautilus from the command line to see if it threw up some kind of error regarding the extension. Unfortunately as soon as I attempted this nautilus forked to the background or something.

How can I see exactly why my extension isn't work?

Comment: Is there a file in your home folder called `nautilus-debug-log.txt`?

Comment: On a standard install Nautilus is always running in the background (and will be restarted automaticly by gnome-session if you try to kill it).  Because of that, the nautilus you start just tells the existing nautilus process to open a new window and then exits, returning you to the commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want nautilus to stop permanently, open up `gconf-editor` and set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components_list to `windowmanager,panel` (removing "filemanager").  Then log out and back in.

To restore previous behavior, change the gconf key back to `windowmanager,panel,filemanager`.

Answer (score 3):

I recall I was able to run nautilus from a terminal when debugging extensions myself; if you kill and then immediately restart nautilus, you should have it running from the command line:

```
nautilus -q && nautilus ~/
```

I was able to confirm that this works on Lucid. Note that passing in some directory when launching nautilus is important, otherwise it will fork off in the background.

Comment: Using `--browser` instead of some directory probably works too.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best way to debug a Nautilus extension is using Python's logging module to log stuff to a file.
So you could do something like this

```
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
import logging

class MyExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    
        def __init__(self):
            logging.basicConfig(filename="/your/path/pyext.log",
                        filemode='a',
                        format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                        level=logging.DEBUG)
```

And then throw `logging.info()`s around in your code.